# How to make regex, which skips some text to match specific word, match only once?

Tags: regex

I have a regex which skips some words to match a specific word. I want it to match only the first occurrence of that specific word.

For example,

I have a regex `(full)(\s+\S+){0,10}?\s+(amount)` and my sample text is

> liable for full amount but only in access of the full amount

The result of above match is:

> full amount
>   full amount

I only want the first occurrence of the `full amount`

Comment: What tool or programming language are you using?

Comment: Get rid of global flag or add `.*` at the end of regex so it matches the rest of the text and not generate a second match. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/B9DKTT/1)

Comment: You could use an anchor to assert the start of the string `^.*?` You might update your pattern to `^.*?(full)(?:\s+\S+){0,10}?\s+(amount)` https://regex101.com/r/joZSlT/1

Comment: @blhsing the language is c# but I cannot change the code. It uses regex.matches() function.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi i just want to return the first occurrence of "full amount", not the rest of the text as a single match.

Comment: @ImranLatif But your pattern uses capturing groups to match what is between those words using `(\s+\S+){0,10}?`. Does that logic still apply?

Comment: @ImranLatif: Check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55733756/2102956) Hopefully this should be what you were looking for. It captures the first occurrence of `full some optional text amount` into group1.

Answer (score 0):

Using the part to skip some words, you could use and anchor `^` to assert the start of the string and match any char 0+ times non greedy using `.*?`

Then use 2 capturing groups where the part in the middle can be turned into a non capturing group:

```
^.*?\b(full)(?:\s+\S+){0,10}?\s+(amount)\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Sbf1gc/1) | [C# demo](https://ideone.com/62txci)

For example:

```
String str = @"liable for full amount but only in access of the full amount";
Match m = Regex.Match(str, @"^.*?(full)(?:\s+\S+){0,10}?\s+(amount)");      
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", m.Groups[1].Value, m.Groups[2].Value);
```

Result:

```
full amount
```

Comment: Is there any way this could be done without getting into code?

Comment: You can just get the first and second capturing group. Did you check the regex demo?

Comment: @ImranLatif Do you mean like this getting only the match instead of a capturing group? https://ideone.com/nLJOCt